# GTX 760 dual monitor (DVI and VGA)

Tags: multiple-monitors, nvidia-graphics-card

I have a problem with my graphic card.
I have a VGA monitor and an HDMI TV connected, both via DVI->VGA and DVI->HDMI. The Problem is my PC works with only the monitor and doesn't find TV in devices.

I'm running Windows 7 professional N

Has someone had a similar problem and fixed it?

Comment: Welcome to Super User. This question is lacking details needed for anyone to be able to help you. Please add details of what you have tried so far, including equipment information (i.e. brand and model numbers), and exactly what you expect to accomplish. If you need more info about asking questions, check out ***[ask]*** in the ***[help]***.

Answer (score 0):

If the card doesn't have two display ports you're most likely only using 1 graphics controller (probably the Graphic card). You'll have to enable your onboard graphics.

Refer to this article: http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/embedded/software/emgd/hybrid-multi-monitor-support-paper.html